# 'raster' package getData function not working

Tags: r, raster, rcpp

I want to use worldclim data for species distribution modelling. I want to download the worldclim data directly into RStudio (download on their website does currently not work, at least for me). I used following code:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

climdata <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=30)
```

I got following error code:

> Error in getData("worldclim", var = "bio", res = 30) : could not find function "getData"

After `library(raster)` I also got some errors:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in .doLoadActions(where, attach):
> error in load action .**A**.1 for package raster: loadModule(module = "spmod", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "spmod": function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: Upgrade `Rcpp` (`install.packages("Rcpp")` ) and then try to install `raster` again.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't helped. I deinstalled R, RStudio and all packages and after installing all of it again it worked.